# How can I capture part of a URI with a C# RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to capture part of a path in a URI to validate if the user has rights to access it. In each case below I need to capture the word `organization`

```
https://ww.somedomain.com/api/v1/organization
https://ww.somedomain.com/api/v1/organization/
https://ww.somedomain.com/api/v1/organization/1234
```

https://regex101.com/r/iV81VC/1

Comment: There are far better ways in both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core to authorize requests than parsing a URL. Beyond that, you can parse the string into a Uri and check the contents of [Uri.Segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-8.0)

Comment: If you use ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI or ASP.NET Core (any stack) you can capture the `organization` part in a route template